# go 1.18 generic compile error when use maps.Copy on map with struct key

Tags: go, generics, compiler-errors

I implemented a Set based on generic, and everything ok until i use struct as Set element instead of base type. I got an compliation error.

go version: `go version go1.18 windows/amd64`

Below code is failed to complie in function `AddSet`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/exp/maps"
)

type Key struct {
    A, B int
}

func main() {
    s := SetOf(
        Key{1, 1},
        Key{2, 2},
        Key{3, 3},
    )
    s.AddSet(SetOf(
        Key{3, 3},
        Key{4, 4},
        Key{5, 5},
    ))

    fmt.Println(s)
}

type Set[T comparable] map[T]struct{}

func SetOf[T comparable](vs ...T) Set[T] {
    s := Set[T]{}
    for _, v := range vs {
        s[v] = struct{}{}
    }
    return s
}

func (s Set[T]) AddSet(another Set[T]) {
    maps.Copy(s, another)
}
```

when run it:

```
> go run .\main.go
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:19:10: cannot use &.autotmp_29 (type *struct { A int; B int }) as type *Key in argument to runtime.mapassign
<autogenerated>:1: cannot use &.autotmp_12 (type *struct { A int; B int }) as type *Key in argument to runtime.mapassign
```

- if `Key` only has 1 field, it can be compiled successful.
- if i use `for v := range another { s[v]=struct{}{} }`, it can be compiled successful.

i think it's strange, can someone explain please?

Comment: As a workaround (until it gets fixed), you may use a manual conversion before passing `s` to `maps.Copy()` like this: `maps.Copy(map[T]struct{}(s), another)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [this compiler error](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51840). It is fixed in Go 1.19 and backported to Go 1.18.2.

If you are on an older version, I'd recommend simply forgoing the `maps` package and doing things by hand, as you already tried. It's just a simple loop:

```
func (s Set[T]) AddSet(another Set[T]) {
    for k := range another {
        s[k] = struct{}{}
    }
}
```

@icza's comment of explicitly converting the named map type to its underlying type also works:

```
maps.Copy(map[T]struct{}(s), another)
```

In case you use functions that expect more than one map type parameter (with the same constraints), as `maps.Equal` or `maps.EqualFunc`, you have to convert both arguments:

```
func (s Set[T]) Compare(another Set[T]) bool {
    // signature is Equal[M1, M2 ~map[K]V, K, V comparable](m1 M1, m2 M2) bool
    return maps.Equal(map[T]struct{}(s), map[T]struct{}(another))
}
```

---

It seems the crash was [reproduced](https://go.dev/play/p/233rQRQglXG) also with parametrized map types instantiated with arrays with len >= 2.